# Como fazer um Select para não exibir resultado zerado?

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho o select abaixo, que me traz sempre duas linhas, uma com zero e outra com valor:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ROMANEIO) ROMANEIO FROM PCN_ROMANEIO_DISTR_ITEM WHERE USUARIO = 'junior'
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ROMANEIO) ROMANEIO FROM PCN_ROMANEIO_DISTR_ITEM WHERE USUARIO_EMPILHADEIRA = 'junior'
```

O resultado é o abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que precisaria é fazer com que só fosse exibido o resultado com valor maior que 0. Somente um terá valor, sempre. Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use um [Subselect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487138.aspx) e faça o filtro do resultado do select internor.

```
select * from 
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ROMANEIO) ROMANEIO FROM PCN_ROMANEIO_DISTR_ITEM WHERE USUARIO = 'junior'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ROMANEIO) ROMANEIO FROM PCN_ROMANEIO_DISTR_ITEM WHERE USUARIO_EMPILHADEIRA = 'junior'
)saida
where saida.ROMANEIO > 0
```

Comment: Simples e eficiente. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar a clausula HAVING para filtrar valores agregados:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ROMANEIO) ROMANEIO 
  FROM PCN_ROMANEIO_DISTR_ITEM 
 WHERE USUARIO = 'junior'
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ROMANEIO) > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ROMANEIO) ROMANEIO 
  FROM PCN_ROMANEIO_DISTR_ITEM 
 WHERE USUARIO_EMPILHADEIRA = 'junior 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ROMANEIO) > 0;
```